# android can't establish URL connection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

i've an application that was act properly when i run it with android 2.3.6(Ginger Bread), but when i run it on 4.2 it did'nt work with the URL connection, it can't establish the connection
here is the snip of the code that performs the URL connection :

```
try {
                Add.setEnabled(true);
                movieContent.setText("");
                String TITLE =searchET.getText().toString();
                TITLE = TITLE.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.d("title after parsing:", TITLE);
                URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t="
                        + TITLE);
                String URL2="http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=saw";
                Log.d("URL content", url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Log.d("URL content", "register URL");
                urlConnection.connect();
                Log.d("URL connection", "establish connection");
```

the log cat shows that the flow reach "register URL" log print it then raise a warning in green labeled as QCNEA:

`03-21 23:53:56.596: D/title after parsing:(16623): saw
03-21 23:53:56.596: D/URL content(16623): http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=saw
03-21 23:53:56.596: D/URL content(16623): register URL
03-21 23:53:56.596: I/QCNEA(16623): |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname www.omdbapi.com servname NULL numeric 4 appname 
03-21 23:53:56.616: I/MediaPlayer(16623): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
03-21 23:53:57.207: V/MediaPlayer(16623): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-21 23:53:57.207: V/MediaPlayer(16623): playback complete
03-21 23:53:57.207: V/MediaPlayer(16623): callback application
03-21 23:53:57.207: V/MediaPlayer(16623): back from callback`

knowing that all permission regarding connection are added.

the weird thing that there is no error , just can't establish the connection.

hope you guys help me with this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get this error if you using the Android emulator, or does this only happen on a specific device?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be running into issues with doing networking code on the main thread, though I'm not sure why you're not getting an error or app crash.

Put your code in an Async task and see if it works.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncLoad = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t="
                    + TITLE);
            String URL2="http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=saw";
            Log.d("URL content", url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            Log.d("URL content", "register URL");
            urlConnection.connect();
            Log.d("URL connection", "establish connection");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    };

    asyncLoad.execute();
```

Comment: i've put my code without AsynTask in a separate project adding 
`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); `
and it's worked , but when i put it the same without any modification it raise this problem i don't know why !!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between gingerbread and higher versions is the strict policy about networking on main thread. When you change strict mode to permit all you allow tour activities to do that networking on main thread... But you shouldnt do that... You should go by the rules and run an async task Just like the one suggested by @JustSoAmazing.

Answer (score 0):

First, append following into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Second, try this

```
int timeout = 15 * 1000; // timeout in 15 seconds 

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
urlConnection.connect();

// ...
```